# Spring Boot on Tomcat 9 Fails to Map Controllers (404's)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

My Spring boot application packaged as ROOT.war on tomcat9 using Java 11 appears to load successfully but fails to map the controllers. I can view every page by going right to the .jsp but my controller's map the URL's without .jsp. If I go to the mapped URL I get the standard 404 page.

This app works locally but expresses this behavior on my remote VM.

I've not seen this before and can't find anything relevant in my logs. I have another application with the exact same setup that works fine. What am I missing and/or what should I try next?

Here is my context file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiResourceLocking="true" path=""/>
```

Using standard spring application setup:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
```

And a basic request mapping and ModelAndView response:

```
@RestController
public class PageController extends BasePageController {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PageController.class);

    @Autowired       private Configuration configuration;

    @Autowired
    private OrderManager orderManager;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView indexSlash(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1) {
```

This works fine locally and for another app with the same setup, making me think its some minor version issue. I am using tomcat 9.0.34 and Java 11.0.7. There is nothing in my app log. Here is my catalina.out file after startup:

```
NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS:  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
31-May-2020 15:33:46.744 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.34
31-May-2020 15:33:46.748 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Apr 3 2020 12:02:52 UTC
31-May-2020 15:33:46.748 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 9.0.34.0
31-May-2020 15:33:46.749 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
31-May-2020 15:33:46.749 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            5.3.0-1022-azure
31-May-2020 15:33:46.749 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
31-May-2020 15:33:46.749 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
31-May-2020 15:33:46.749 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-2ubuntu218.04
31-May-2020 15:33:46.750 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Ubuntu
31-May-2020 15:33:46.750 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /usr/local/tomcat9
31-May-2020 15:33:46.751 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/local/tomcat9
31-May-2020 15:33:46.786 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
31-May-2020 15:33:46.787 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
31-May-2020 15:33:46.787 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
31-May-2020 15:33:46.787 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat9/conf/logging.properties
31-May-2020 15:33:46.787 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
31-May-2020 15:33:46.788 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
31-May-2020 15:33:46.788 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
31-May-2020 15:33:46.789 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
31-May-2020 15:33:46.789 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
31-May-2020 15:33:46.789 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomcat9
31-May-2020 15:33:46.789 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat9
31-May-2020 15:33:46.792 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat9/temp
31-May-2020 15:33:46.792 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not $
31-May-2020 15:33:47.542 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
31-May-2020 15:33:47.606 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [1,342] milliseconds
31-May-2020 15:33:47.738 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
31-May-2020 15:33:47.744 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.34]
31-May-2020 15:33:47.800 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/usr/local/tomcat9/webapps/ROOT.war]
31-May-2020 15:33:47.831 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ExpandWar.expand An expanded directory [/usr/local/tomcat9/webapps/ROOT] was found with a last modified time that did not match the associated W$
31-May-2020 15:33:54.545 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs $
31-May-2020 15:33:55.095 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/usr/local/tomcat9/webapps/ROOT.war] has finished in [7,295] ms
31-May-2020 15:33:55.100 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat9/webapps/host-manager]
31-May-2020 15:33:55.166 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat9/webapps/host-manager] has finished in [66] ms
31-May-2020 15:33:55.167 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat9/webapps/docs]
31-May-2020 15:33:55.207 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat9/webapps/docs] has finished in [40] ms
31-May-2020 15:33:55.208 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat9/webapps/examples]
31-May-2020 15:33:55.581 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat9/webapps/examples] has finished in [373] ms
31-May-2020 15:33:55.581 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat9/webapps/manager]
31-May-2020 15:33:55.625 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat9/webapps/manager] has finished in [43] ms
31-May-2020 15:33:55.633 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
31-May-2020 15:33:55.667 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [8,059] milliseconds
```

Comment: show the package of the classes

Comment: both the application and configurations are in the same package

Comment: I am not sure this is a Spring problem (but the issue is not totally clear to me from your explaination). Try enabling the debug log level for spring and check the log. If it is a spring issue it should be very clear stated in the logs. Hth!

Comment: Thanks Nik. I'll give that a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so as I expected, this was self inflicted. Turns out I had one dev machine set to build the project with Java 11 (same as my remote server) and another set to build the project with Java 14. The Java 14 version failed to deploy, go figure.

It's worth noting for others with the same symptoms that tomcat will explode and "deploy" a war that doesn't work so all the jsp, css, etc will show up yet the actual java code won't work. It also seems to be very limited in logging when this happen so you wont see anything indicating that it failed or why it failed.

To debug, I suggest using Nik's advise and set spring to debug level. I'd also suggest mirroring the dev environment exactly the same as the remote server to avoid these version alignment issues.

Answer (score 0):

@RequestMapping is missing.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/page")
public class PageController extends BasePageController { }
```

Comment: @RequestMapping is on the method level as shown in the code. Per Spring documentation: Note: This annotation can be used both at the class and at the method level.

Comment: Ok, i see that your code is mixed fullstack and rest